# Redirect to another URL from root URL of web application

Tags: apache, redirect

In my web application, current landing page (root URL) is `landflo.com` 
I would like it to be so that when a user goes to `landflo.com` they will autmatically get `landflo.com/login` (which is currently a page on my server.).

Basically I want the root to be `landflo.com/login`.

Here is my `httpd-app.conf`file contents:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/public">
PassengerEnabled on
Options -MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
Require all granted
</IfVersion>

PassengerAppRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs"
</Directory>

PassengerPreStart http://127.0.0.1:80
```

and my `httpd-prefix.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/public/"
Include /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/conf/httpd-app.conf
```

Please let me have a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: You can use RewriteEngine for it. Just add "RewriteEngine on" and proper RewriteRule (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html )

Comment: Do I add this into the httpd-app.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RewriteEngine for it. Just add "RewriteEngine on" and proper RewriteRule (see httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html )